# How do I create a 3-way LEFT JOIN with MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to create a 3-way LEFT JOIN using MYSQL and I'm having difficulty accomplishing it so I figured this would be the place to figure it out.

I have a three tables as I'll display below. The first contains a list of items that a user has added to their queue to be processed by the game. The other two contain details about each of the items such as their strengths, points to completion, etc. In the queued table, I have two types of items, units and research. The unit details are found in table 2 and the research details are found in table 3.

**Table 1:** The first table (core_queued_units) contains the following fields: id, unit_id, name, location, class(unit or research),sort.

**Table 2:** The second table (core_available_units) contains the following fields: id, name, description, etc.

**Table 3:** The third table (core_available_tech) contains the following fields: id, name, description, etc.

```
FROM core_queued_units
LEFT JOIN core_available_units
ON core_queued_units.unit_id = core_available_units.id
AND core_queued_units.class='Unit'
LEFT JOIN core_available_tech
ON core_queued_units.unit_id = core_available_tech.id
AND core_queued_units.class='Research'
WHERE core_queued_units.location = '1'
AND core_queued_units.user_id ='".$GLOBALS['self']['usrID']."'
ORDER BY core_queued_units.sort ASC
```

Comment: Show the schema. By looking at the list of column names We can not tell which one is the foreign key.

Comment: What difficulty you face for this query? http://pastie.org/3591671

Comment: When I run the first left join and remove the second, it works just fine, however, I have no information on any of the techs...only the units as that's what the first join pulls in. Once I add the second join, all the information for the units disappears from the queued table as if it's trying to use the second table as the left side of the second join.

Comment: Just wondering: are you sure you mean `ON core_queued_units.unit_id = core_available_tech.id` in the second `LEFT JOIN`? Or could it be that you meant `tech_id` and not `unit_id`. Or to put it another way, what is the foreign key in `core_queued_units` with respect to `core_available_tech`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If fields in `core_available_units` and `core_available_tech` are equal, you can try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM core_queued_units cq
  LEFT JOIN (
     select cau.*, 'Unit' class from core_available_units cau
      union all
     select cat.*, 'Research' class from core_available_tech cat) c
    ON cq.unit_id = c.unit_id and c.class = cq.class
WHERE cq.location = '1'
  AND cq.user_id ='".$GLOBALS['self']['usrID']."'
ORDER BY cq.sort ASC
```

Comment: He can fills the Union with Constants if the fields aren't equal?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to join multiple tables, you can do as follows. I am taking Table1 as base table.

```
SELECT columnname1, columnname2......
FROM Table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.PK = Table2.FK (here Table2.FK is the Primary key of Table1 which is used as Foreign key in Table2)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.PK = Table3.FK (same condition as above) 
WHERE insert your conditions here
```

using this sample, columns from Table2 & Table3 will added at the right most side of Table1.
Please inform if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to swap the arguments in the On-clause

`core_queued_units.unit_id = core_available_tech.id`?